# Form view update issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview, master-detail

I am using asp.net with a c# back end to create a job website with a master and detail view.
To pull data I am using entity framework that was reverse engineered code first from a SQL server 2005 instance running on the same xp machine that I am doing development on. I would like the detail view on the website to be able view and edit existing records selected on the master view, but also be able to insert records.

 So far I gotten to the point where the detail view can be used both view and insert records but editing has been unsuccessful as of yet. I don't get an error on update, and the I see no change reflected anywhere.

 Some of the solutions I've seen say that you have to have DataKeyNames defined. (In my case I have used a field: Job_UID, which is actually how I connected the detail and master views.) 
I have tried to made sure that I have the update query defined properly by reducing the number of items in the where clause to just reflect my PK and also by testing the query in the query designer. 
Here are my queries:

***SelectCommand**="SELECT Job_Details.Job_UID, Job_Details.Job_Title, Job_Details.Job_Store_ID, Job_Details.Job_Type_Id, Job_Details.Job_Description, Job_Details.Job_Responsibilities, Job_Details.Job_Pay, Job_Details.Job_Supervisor, Job_Details.Job_Start_Date, Job_Details.Job_End_Date, Job_Details.Job_Meta_Post_StartDate, Job_Details.Job_Meta_Post_EndDate, Job_Details.Job_Meta_Keywords, Store_Look_Up.Store_Name, Store_Look_Up.Store_Region, Store_Look_Up.Store_Address, Job_Type.Job_Type_Name, Job_Type.Job_Type_Description FROM Job_Details INNER JOIN Job_Type ON Job_Details.Job_Type_Id = Job_Type.Job_Type_Id INNER JOIN Store_Look_Up ON Job_Details.Job_Store_ID = Store_Look_Up.Store_Id WHERE (Job_Details.Job_UID = @Job_UID)" 
               
  **InsertCommand**="INSERT INTO Job_Details(Job_UID, Job_Title, Job_Store_ID, Job_Type_Id, Job_Description, Job_Responsibilities, Job_Pay, Job_Supervisor, Job_Start_Date, Job_End_Date, Job_Meta_Post_StartDate, Job_Meta_Post_EndDate, Job_Meta_Keywords) VALUES (@Job_UID, @Job_Title, @Job_Store_ID, @Job_Type_Id, @Job_Description, @Job_Responsibilities, @Job_Pay, @Job_Supervisor, @Job_Start_Date, @Job_End_Date, @Job_Meta_Post_StartDate, @Job_Meta_Post_EndDate, @Job_Meta_Keywords)" 
               
  **UpdateCommand**="UPDATE Job_Details SET Job_Title = @Job_Title, Job_Store_ID = @Job_Store_ID, Job_Type_Id = @Job_Type_Id, Job_Description = @Job_Description, Job_Responsibilities = @Job_Responsibilities, Job_Pay = @Job_Pay, Job_Supervisor = @Job_Supervisor, Job_Start_Date = @Job_Start_Date, Job_End_Date = @Job_End_Date, Job_Meta_Post_StartDate = @Job_Meta_Post_StartDate, Job_Meta_Post_EndDate = @Job_Meta_Post_EndDate, Job_Meta_Keywords = @Job_Meta_Keywords WHERE **(Job_UID = @Original__Job_UID)">***

The rest of the solutions I've seen seem to involve a lot of custom coding. Shouldn't there be a way to do this just using Visual Studio's code generator, with some coding tweaks?

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my update command:

I used the ItemUpdatedEvent of my FormView to determine how many rows were modified: 0 in my case.

```
        string textToDisplay = string.Empty;
        textToDisplay += "AffectedRows: " + e.AffectedRows.ToString() + "|";

        Label1.Text = textToDisplay;
```

Once I was clearly able to see how many rows were being updated, I proceeded to test the query. I replaced @Original_Job_UID with the PK. And it worked on the page.
Then I looked through some MSDN documentation and saw that the filter should have been
@Job_UID. I entered it and it worked!

Hope this helps you!